# Persisting a model on bound property change

Tags: javascript, performance, ember.js, debouncing

What is the best practice for immediately persisting a model, when one of it's attributes is bound to a template input? Does it belong to the model or the controller, in your opinion?

I came up with this solution, based on an observer:

```
# Models
App.Foo = DS.Model.extend
  bars: DS.hasMany('bars')

App.Bar = DS.Model.extend
  quantity: DS.attr('number')

# Template
{{#each bar in bars}}
  {{input value=bar.quantity}}
{{/each}}

# Controller
persistQuantity: ( ->
  @get('bars').forEach (bar) -> bar.save() if bar.get('isDirty')
).observes('bars.@each.quantity')
```

But this fires multiple (3 for me) save requests for the same model for some reason.

I also tried to put the observer on the model, but this went to an endless loop:

```
# App.Bar Model
  persistQuantity: ( ->
    @save()
  ).observes('quantity')
```

I tried to fix that through `Ember.run.once`, but my understanding of the Ember run loop wasn't deep enough, apparently.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Where it belongs depends on whether or not you want the model to save whenever it changes, or only save when it changes from a particular view.  If you want the model to always save, regardless of where it's saved, do it on the model.  If you want to control saving it from a particular view do it in the controller.

Debouncing would be my favorite option for solving the multiple call issue.  Watching a particular item, then automatically saving when it changes.  You could also watch `isDirty` and fire when it changes, but I'm more a fan of the other pattern (though isDirty scales better, it's less informative).  Here's both patterns, feel free to mix and match as appropriate.

Have the model auto save when dirty:

```
App.Bar = DS.Model.extend
  quantity: DS.attr('number'),
  watchDirty: function(){
    if(this.get('isDirty')){
      this.save();
    }
  }.observes('isDirty')
```

Example: http://emberjs.jsbin.com/OxIDiVU/898/edit

Have the model queue saving when an item gets dirty (or multiple items)

```
App.Bar = DS.Model.extend({
    quantity: DS.attr(),  
    watchQuantity: function(){
      if(this.get('isDirty')){
        Em.run.debounce(this, this.save, 500); 
      }
    }.observes('quantity')
});
```

Example: http://emberjs.jsbin.com/OxIDiVU/897/edit

Comment: Excellent! By the way, I tried to remove the ``realSave`` proxy from the debounce call (``Em.run.debounce(this, this.save, 500);``), and it seem to work just fine. Am I missing something?

Comment: Oh yes, sorry, I was kind of doing two different versions and left it hacky like.  That's totally cool like so.